# How to retrieve the text in actual-data tag?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, nodelist

My xml file is as follows :

```
<xml>
    <group id="1">
        <dstport>8080</dstport>
        <packet id="1">
            <comp type="const">
                <actual-data><![CDATA[GET /]]></actual-data>
                <binary><![CDATA[47 45 54 20 2f ]]></binary>
            </comp>
            <comp type="var">
                <actual-data><![CDATA[host-manager/html HTTP]]></actual-data>
                <binary><![CDATA[68 6f 73 74 2d 6d 61 6e 61 67 65 72 2f 68 74 6d 6c 20 48 54 54 50 ]]></binary>
            </comp>
        </packet>
    </group>
</xml>
```

I want to retrieve the text in `actual-data` tag
(in this case -"host-manager/html HTTP")

I am trying with this:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/xml
                                         /group
                                            /packet
                                               /comp
                                                  /actual-data
                                                     /text()");
```

But it is giving null string.
Is it because of that [CDATA] thing. I haven't figured what that is. Is it a tag or attribute?

Can anyone give the query to get the deserved data.
(in this case -"host-manager/html HTTP")

Comment: also note, there are 2 matches in this doc ("GET /" is the first match)

Comment: This is not about XPath but usage of XPath results data types. Retagging.

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath expression is ambiguous:

This code:

```
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("test.xml");
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("
                              /xml/group/packet/comp/actual-data/text()");
String s = expr.evaluate(inputSource);
System.out.println(s);
```

Will display:

```
GET /
```

which is the contents of the first actual-data tag. If you want the second one, you should be more specific:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("
                       /xml/group/packet/comp[@type='var']/actual-data/text()");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 results. So, if you want both of the items to come back, to the following:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String xpathExpression = "/xml/group/packet/comp/actual-data";
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("test.xml");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath
    .evaluate(xpathExpression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
int j = nodes.getLength();
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
  System.out.println("node:" + nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```